# php class error, it wont echo teacher

Tags: php

this is my code and the class is messed up, so it wont echo

```
class Person  __construct($firstname,$lastname,$age)
{
    public $isAlive = true;
    $firstname->prop1 = $firstname;
    $lastname->prop2 = $lastname;
    $age->prop3 = $age;
 }
 $teacher = new Person("boring", "12345", 12345);
 $student = new Person("boringw", "12345w", 12345);
 echo $teacher;
```

Comment: Can you post your _actual_ code? This is barely readable, and your `<?php` opening tag is incorrectly pasted.

Comment: This code is riddled with syntax errors. It isn't even close to correct. I suggest starting over and referring to the manual often.

Comment: sorry for the terrible syntax, im new to php and now ive lost like 10 points i would just like to understand this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As people have mentioned in the comments, your code is filled with all sorts of errors. What I believe you want is this:

```
class Person {
   function __construct($firstname,$lastname,$age) {
       $this->isAlive   = true;
       $this->firstname = $firstname;
       $this->lastname  = $lastname;
       $this->age       = $age;
    }
}

$teacher = new Person("boring", "12345", 12345);
$student = new Person("boringw", "12345w", 12345);
print_r($teacher);
```

This code has been tested and it works.

### Results:

Person Object ( [isAlive] => 1 [firstname] => boring [lastname] => 12345 [age] => 12345 )

**Note:** You cannot `echo` an object.

Comment: OK thank-you, could you explain it to me because i want to understand it not just get the answer.

Comment: Well you have all sorts of fundamental issues I suggest reading this: [Classes and Objects](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php)